# Is it allright to use/wave the Argentinian flag?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, symbols-symbology, secular-culture

The Sun of May in the flag is inspired by an ancient Inca god. It is used by the Argentinian flag and the Uruguayan flag.

It is a representation used as a homage to the ancient empire, **inspired** by the Inca sun deity, as there isn't an official symbol to represent it, just like we don't have a symbol to represent Hashem.

It is not like the Turkey flag. Muslims adopted the crescent, a secular symbol, to represent their faith, contrariwise, the Sun of May was never adopted by Incan faith, neither it was made to symbolize it.

Is it idolatry to use/wave these flags, but without adoring the symbol?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya user9323. Thank you for asking this question. Conider learning more about the site by taking a brief tour: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour. For general help see here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help. Hope to see you around.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45264/is-it-problematic-to-own-and-use-a-swiss-gear-bag

Comment: Doesn't the Japanese flag have a similar notion. IIRC, the red circle is a representation of the sun, which they used as a god?

Answer (score 1):

When an idolatrous cult is over you are free to go into its former temples, posess any objects that were formerly used in the cult, use symbols that were formerly associated with that cult. There are even situations when you can do this with currently active idolatrous cults, though you must check it well in advance and be careful all the way. Can you enter a beautiful church just to see the paintings? You may, if the church is seldom used for cult and has become more of a museum. Not if its main purpose is to serve the cult, no matter how beautiful it is. But you can always look at photographs of it. Idols are dead, even when they are currently being worshipped by someone, more the reason they are dead when no one is paying them attention any more.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Kielecki, and thanks for answering this question (it's waited a long time!). We don't know who you are, so it's best if you include your sources when posting an answer. Please [edit] your post to include whatever sources you can. I hope you enjoy participating here. :)