# Waving or otherwise recognizing the English flag and its variants

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, christianity

Related to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57535/is-it-allright-to-use-wave-the-argentinian-flag) and [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45264/is-it-problematic-to-own-and-use-a-swiss-gear-bag) the English flag and many of its variants from [former colonies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_England) have the cross of someone who is recognized as a saint by Catholics, George. This cross was used as a flag in the Crusades as a rallying point around the wars fought for their religious reasons (and the Crusades have a particularly painful memory in Judaism as well, even being remember in the Kinos on Tisha B'Av).

Although, on the other hand, the recognition of a saint [may not rise](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57555/status-of-catholic-saints-in-judaism) to the level of a cross, and the cross in this context may be more viewed as a symbol of the person than of the religion.

Is there an issue waving, recognizing or otherwise honoring the flags that contain this symbol?